# Importing Pledges

Tags: pledges

I am doing a billing. We enter items as pledges. I need a way to import the pledges from a spreadsheet. Last year I imported directly into the pledge table and did not realize I needed to also load the pledge_payment table. The pledge_payment is more complicated as you need the pledge number. Looking for an easy way to load both.

Answer (score 4):

The [API csv Import GUI extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui) will allow you to import pledges. You can import the pledges and then separately, the contributions marked as pledge payments that correspond to the needed pledges.

Note: When you import the contributions, you will need a column for "pledge payment" that is marked Y for each row.  Also, you will need a column with the corresponding pledge number for each row so the import knows which pledge the contribution goes to.

Comment: Allen. This looks promising but I am unable to import the pledge payments. 
I tried to do it from the contribution importer (I inlcuded the pledge payment columns with y for each row along with the pledge ID) I get a very vague error that isn't helpful. I also tried to import as pledge payments from API csv but no luck. I get an error there as well. Any ideas or insights you can share?

Comment: Oh boy, the last time I used that extension was two years ago.  I know you said the error was vague, but what was the text of it?

Answer (score 0):

We solved the current problem using a tool called Selenium. It is basically a testing tool, but you can record a script and create an XML file with each line having the data for one transaction. The tool simulates a user at a browser.  Took about 5 hours time from an experienced programmer to setup.  For 300 transactions we probably broke even on time but being a nonprofit the labor was volunteer. If we had to pay for the developer it would have been less expensive to hire a temp.

Our plan for next year is to code a module so our office staff can easily import a CSV file.