# Importing and updating pledges

Tags: import, pledges

I want to import a bulk pledges to my CiviCRM installation and also I need to updating the pledges in every month. If I do it in manual it is very time consuming process. is there any easy way like import to update the pledges ?

Answer (score 1):

You can import pledges with the API csv Import GUI extension mentioned in these questions:

[api csv import - cannot find start page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/10375/105)

[Importing Pledges](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/6378/105)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in pledge import like there is for contributions. By updating the pledge each month, do you mean recording payments against them? If so, then as of 4.6, you can use batch data entry to enter payments against pledges, but only cash/check payments, not credit card payments - instructions can be found at the following link: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/pledges/everyday-tasks/