# api csv import - cannot find start page

Tags: import

I have installed the api csv importer

https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui

I cannot find where the start page is.

I have looked in read me which says civicrm/csvimporter/import

However I get an error message CRM_Core_Config::$maxImportFileSize.

I had this problem once before and managed via google to find the answer. Frustratingly I did not write it down and now cannot work out how to get round this. Has anyone got any tips?
Thanks
Caroline

Answer (score 1):

you are correct, the page is civicrm/csvimporter/import

(as defined here: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/blob/master/xml/Menu/csvimport.xml)

Your error is something else, like not having a compatible civicrm version. Can you give more details on your configuration? what version of civicrm and what CMS do you use (drupal, wordpress or joomla)?

Comment: Hello, yes my civicrm is Powered by CiviCRM 4.7.3; drupal 7.43