# Using API csv Import GU"I extension for Pledges

Tags: extension, import

I have a number of Pledges that need to be loaded and was hoping the the extension would allow me to create a csv file and import the pledges in bulk. A separate line was created for each 'payment' of the pledge, the Contact ID was used as the key and a sequential number was allocated as the Pledge ID. The extension appeared to work as the returned message indicated that all records had been successfully imported.
However, when I view the Contact record, or search pledges, none of the records loaded are visible.
What am I doing wrong? Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Only the Pledges are being loaded at this point. Once those are in, I will try the Contributions. I used your suggested post to try loading two pledges. The load consisted of all the fields that I could get into the API with a row for each expected Contribution. This approach was followed as Civi appears to create all the records when a pledge is loaded manually.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are importing pledges and the contributions relative to each pledge in the same import.  You have to import pledges and their connected contributions separately.  You must also add a couple of columns in order to have things connect correctly.

See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/6380/105